# SQL Server transaction log of update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in SQL Server. I am new to SQL Server so I still have many things to understand. Now I have a table `Student`. When I update a row in my table, I want to see it in the transaction log that what value is updated and then I want to revert back that to old values.

Comment: Reverting back is simple: do your update in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, and `ROLLBACK` at the end. If you want to study the transaction log for educational purposes, that's only possible with undocumented commands. Look for information on the `fn_dblog` function. In production code, the transaction log should be treated as a black box that's maintained by the server; its contents are not accessible to applications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply just look at the transaction log and get the previous value of a column. To get the previous value you'd need to restore the transaction log backup(s).

If you need easy access to all of the past values, I recommend creating an StudentAuditLog  table. Before modifying data on the Student table insert the old values to StudentAuditLog and then update the Student table.